# Get Rounded Corner in Maximized Windows in Gnome

Tags: gnome, window

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Gnome Shell 3.36.4.

The titlebar of my windows, when unmaximized, have rounded corners.[image: unmaximized window]

But when I maximize the window, the rounded corner disappears.

[image: maximized window]

How can I get rounded corners in maximized windows?

Comment: Are you using custom shell theme?

Comment: @UnKNOWn, yes, but the same thing happens with default shell theme. I've checked.

Comment: I will also chk in sometime